# HttpClient C#. Как получить чистый html?

Tags: c#, кодировка, httpclient

Мне нужно парсить JSON из ответа на POST запрос, но полученный код страницы не получаеся использовать из-за спец. символов - \n \t. Как можно от них избавится?
Изменение кодировки не помогло.
Возможно надо менять заголовки запроса?

Код получения html

```
var encodedContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(parameters);
        var h = Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TransferEncoding;
        var response = await Client.PostAsync(Uri, encodedContent);
        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
              return  await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
        return null;
```

Ответ:

```
g = "\n<!DOCTYPE HTML>\n<head>\n    <meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0\">\n    <link rel=\"shortcut icon\" href=\"https://******.ru/favicon.ico\" type=\"image/x-icon\">\n    <link rel=\"icon\" h...
```

В ответе на POST запрос есть скрипт с json строкой - `<script> window.CData = [{\"date\":\"2021-08-02\",\"title\":{\"2\":{\"name\":[{\"id\":\"495364\",...`(он очень большой, весь копировать не буду) и проблема в том что десериализовать его не получается, подозреваю что из-за знака '`\`' перед кавычками.

Comment: Это переносы строк и табуляции - у вас же html не в одну строку записан. Если мешают - сделайте .Replace на «»

Comment: Покажите json полностью, какая версия дотнета используется?

Comment: @aepot JSON слишком большой

Comment: ну тогда сами разберите его парсером, примеров полинтернета. Если .NET 5, то [System.Text.Json](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to?pivots=dotnet-5-0), если 4.x, то NuGet пакет `Newtonsoft.Json` вам поможет. Как раз из десереализованных данных вы получите HTML без `\r\n`, а нормальный.

Comment: Как вы вытаскиваете JSON? Что будет если его вывести на экран, будут ли там лишние знаки? Запишите его в файл например и посмотрите (`File.WriteAllText(json);`. Вангую, что вы не так выдераете его из HTML, из за чего у вас лишние символы до и после. Например, `window.CData =`.

Comment: `text = Regex.Unescape(text)`, быть может это вам нужно.

Comment: @aepot он не убирает ' \ '. Но если не получится получить html код без этих знаков, то буду использовать 'Unescape' и какой-нибудь 'Replace'

Comment: @EvgeniyZ JSON получаю из 'window.CData'(убираю все через substring), а 'window.CData' получаю с помощью Angle Sharp через селектор тега. Выводить в текстовый файл пробовал, получается вот это ' [{\u0022date\u0022:\u00222021-08-02\u0022,\u0022  ... '

Comment: `он не убирает ' \ '.` - `text = Regex.Unescape(Regex.Unescape(text))` безвыходных ситуаций не бывает. Вот ещё https://stackoverflow.com/a/52207034/12888024

Comment: @Pyt Что вам пишет десериализатор? Дайте нам полный текст JSON файла и то, как вы его десериализуете. Ибо тот кусок, что вы предоставили в комментарии, я успешно взял и [десериализовал](https://dotnetfiddle.net/R1Ei5g).

Comment: @Pyt содержимое текстового файла говорит вам о том, что никаких слешей строка не содержит. Так что ошибка только в том, что вы **неправильно выдираете json из html**. Ищите ошибку в этой части. Либо (что крайне маловероятно) сервер возвращает некорректный json

Comment: Проверить это просто, достаточно зайти [сюда](https://www.online-toolz.com/tools/text-unicode-entities-convertor.php) и ввести вашу строку `[{\u0022date\u0022:\u00222021-08-02\u0022,\u0022`. Получим: `[{"date":"2021-08-02","`

Comment: @AndreiKhotko это лечится вполне с помощью Regex.Unescape

Answer (score 4):

Избавиться от переносов строк нельзя ни настройкой HttpClient, ни добавлением заголовков в запрос. HttpClient должен отдавать ровно то, что получил от сервера. А сервер не ожидает что переносы строк кому-то могут помешать, и обычно не дает опций для их отключения.

Помимо простейшего совета удалить переносы строк самому с помощью метода String.Replace, могу так же посоветовать не парсить HTML вручную, а использовать [Html Agiligy Pack](https://html-agility-pack.net).

Comment: Уже использую Agility, в JSON есть знаки / , которые мешают его десериализовать   ' [{\"date\":\"2021-08-02\",\"title\":{\"2\" '.

Comment: @Pyt так десереализуйте Json, эта задача еще проще, чем распарсить html

Comment: @Pyt, а можете пояснить что вы имеете в виду под "парсить JSON"? Потому что в вашем вопросе приведен фрагмент HTML документа, у JSON документа формат другой. Распарсить HTML документ можно только инструментами, которые умеют работать с HTML. Не зависимо от того, будут там переносы строк или нет, распарсить HTML документа инструментами для JSON не получится. В чем основная задачу у вас?

Comment: @Uranus в ответе на POST запрос есть скрипт с json строкой - <script> window.CData = [{\"date\":\"2021-08-02\",\"title\":{\"2\":{\"name\":[{\"id\":\"495364\",...(он очень большой, весь копировать не буду) и проблема в том что десериализовать его не получается, подозреваю что из-за знака '\'  перед кавычками.

Comment: @Pyt тогда вам нужно с помощью HTML-парсера сначала извлечь json-строку, а уже потом JSON десериализовывать. Нужно разделить эту задачу на две подзадачи

Comment: @AndreiKhotko, абсолютно с вами согласен, но проблема в том что десериализовать не получается полученную строку. (Полученная строка : " ' [{\"date\":\"2020 - 08 - 01\",\"title\":{\"5\":{"... ' , нужная строка "[{"date":"2020 - 09 - 01","title":{"5":{") Думаю, что надо либо как-то получить html код без знаков \ перед каждыми кавычками либо как-то удалить их после получение кода(хотелось бы использовать первый вариант). Как реализовать второй вариант я представляю.

Comment: @Pyt вы лишь предполагаете, а как на самом деле - нужно выяснить. Со стороны мне кажется, что то значение, где кавычки экранируются - это просто значение, которое показывает дебаггер. На самом же деле, строка может не содержать обратных слешей. Рекомендую сначала вывести значение строки json в файл или консоль, чтобы понять, действительно ли она содержит экранирующие символы